# Assigning an address of an array to a variable and delete

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

My assignment wants me to do this: "Allocate an array of seven ints; initialize it to 1,2,4,8, etc...; and assign its address to a variable  p2"

This was my code:

```
int* p2 = new int[7] {1,2,4,8,16,32,64};
    cout << "Drill 3 & 4 (allocating 7 element array): " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
        cout << p2[i];
    }
```

but I am concerned that I am misunderstanding the instructions. Because of that, I tried this code I found online:

```
int* sev = new int[7];
for (int i = 0; i<7; ++i)
    sev[i] = i+1;
int* p2 = sev;
cout << "p2= " << p2 << ", *p2=" << *p2 << endl;
cout << "sev= " << sev << ", *sev=" << *sev << endl;
```

But it outputs the address and then 1. And when I add a for loop to do it seven times for all of the elements, it's just 1111111.

Is my code above assigning the address to the pointer or doing something different?

I later have to make it equal to p1, which is a pointer (*int p1 = &x, x = 7 <--not code, for reference). And I need to deallocate p1 and p2 (and p3, but that's not relevant). It lets me deallocate p2, but not p1. So, I am thinking maybe I am not understanding the question or am not approaching it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Both the variable `sev` and the variable `p2` are pointing to the *first* element of the data you have allocated. That's really all you have.

So when you dereference the pointers (with e.g. `*sev`) you dereference the pointer to that element only, and get that value only.

A more "graphical" way of looking at your "array" might be like this:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| sev[0] | sev[1] | sev[2] | sev[3] | sev[4] | sev[5] | sev[6] |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
^
|
sev / p2
```

The arrow points to the first element only.